# how can I add data to todo in React?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
  handleClick(){
    alert("CLICKED!!!!");
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="app-header">
        Todo Today
      </div>
      <center>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>ADD</button>
      </center>
      <center>
        <ul>
          <ul>TODO 1</ul>
          <ul>TODO 2</ul>
          <ul>TODO 3</ul>
        </ul>
      </center>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Im building a todo-list with React, and when I handleClick the button, how can I send what has been typed to TODO 1,2,3??

Thank You

Comment: There must be innumerable examples of this out there. It's one of the go-to demo applications.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved like so:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: "",
      todos: []
    };

    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdate(e) {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      input: "",
      todos: [
        ...this.state.todos,
        this.state.input
      ]
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="app-header">Todo Today</div>
        <center>
          <input onChange={this.handleUpdate} value={this.state.input} type="text" />
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>ADD</button>
        </center>
        <center>
          <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map((item, index) => {
            return <li key={index}>{item}</li>
          })}
          </ul>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

[You can find a working example here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-brook-d7oo7)